# write to File from Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets

here is the piece of code that i wrote:

```
public class ServletCounter extends HttpServlet {

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private int serviceCounter = 0;
    private FileOutputStream out;
    private boolean shuttingDown;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(servletConfig);
            }

     @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        enteringServiceMethod();
        try {
            super.service(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\xampp\\tomcat\\webapps\\myapp\\WEB-INF\\lib\\counter.txt");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } 
        @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (!shuttingDown) {
            writeToFile("number of servlet access = " + serviceCounter );

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        ...
    }
    private void enteringServiceMethod() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            serviceCounter++;
            writeToFile("method enteringServiceMethod serviceCounter =  " + serviceCounter);
        }
    }
    private int getNumServices() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return serviceCounter;
        }
    }
    private void writeToFile(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
        text += "\r\n";

        try {
            out.write(text.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

What i need is every time someone opens my Servlet, it should open "counter.txt" file and store a number of how many times the Servlet was opened. for example if the file hold number 8 then after someone accesses the servlet it should store number 9 and delete number 8. does it make sense? can anyone help me override writeToFile method. the code that i wrote is incomplete, but i'm stuck, tried several things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea writting directly, since you will have to deal with concurrent executions (delaying your answer time in the best of the cases, causing invalid values in the worst). When this happens, put a message in a queue and have a single instance process the messages and update the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to count page hit, then `Filter` would be the nice approach

Intercept each request and take a `synchronized` variable in application scope and increment it

Comment: hmmm,i don't think i know how to do it. i've tried using Filter, but i have a problem with my writetoFile method. it does compile, but at runtime, when i start my servlet it throws exceptions and i don't see it at work.

Comment: but why to write to file on each request, You could just manage it in memory and may be at some time interval you could write it to file/DB

Comment: Well this is what i'm asked to do: every time there is an access to ServletCounret, the file should be opened, written down the number of entry and file closed.

Comment: if you want to do it anyways then do it using a synchronized method, It should work, if not for you please tell us the exception stacktrace here

Comment: exception

`
java.lang.NullPointerException
 ServletCounter.writeToFile(ServletCounter.java:80)
 ServletCounter.enteringServiceMethod(ServletCounter.java:67)
 ServletCounter.service(ServletCounter.java:25)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)`.